# sub2Ind matlab to c++/opencv conversion

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I'm trying to create this code in c++/ I'm using openCV but don't have to.

```
 wi = size(Gr, 2);
 he = size(Gr, 1);
 cropFactor = 0.10;
 [x, y] = meshgrid( round(cropFactor * wi):round( (1-cropFactor)*wi ), round(cropFactor * he):round((1-cropFactor)*he) );
 xy = sub2ind(size(Gr), y(:), x(:));
```

here is what I have so far

```
    int width = dst.cols;
    int height = dst.rows;
    double cropFactor = 0.10;


    cv::Mat1i X,Y;
    Utilities::Meshgrid(Utilities::MatlabRound(cropFactor * width), Utilities::MatlabRound((1 - cropFactor) * width), Utilities::MatlabRound(cropFactor * height), Utilities::MatlabRound((1-cropFactor) * height),X, Y);       

    Utilities::Sub2Ind(width, height, X, Y);
```

round() function

```
int Utilities::MatlabRound(double numberToRound)
{
    return floor( numberToRound + 0.5);
}
```

this is my meshgrid() function it works as expected

```
void Utilities::Meshgrid(int startX, int endX, int startY, int endY, cv::Mat1i &X, cv::Mat1i & Y)
{

    std::vector<int> vec_x, vec_y;
    for (int i = startX; i <= endX; i++)
    {
        vec_x.push_back(i);
    }
    for (int i = startY; i <= endY; i++)
    {
        vec_y.push_back(i);
    }
    cv::Mat x = cv::Mat(vec_x);
    cv::Mat y = cv::Mat(vec_y);
    cv::repeat(x.reshape(1,1), y.total(), 1, X);
    cv::repeat(y.reshape(1,1).t(), 1, x.total(), Y);
}
```

however i'm having trouble understanding what are subscripts and how to implement Sub2Ind function

Can you please explain?

**update** I have implemented sub2ind please see my answer

Comment: You should be careful with this, As Matlab stores the matrices column by column and C++ stores them row by row. So `sub2ind` must take this difference into consideration...

Comment: @Shai thanks I know, can you explain how Sub2Ind works?

Comment: I have created sub2Ind function which works for my case with openCV, hope it will help others

Comment: please post your working solution as an answer.

Comment: @Shai ok I have posted my implementation as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have implemented sub2Ind for 2D matrix
it is tested and work fine

```
cv::Mat Utilities::Sub2Ind(int width, int height, cv::Mat X, cv::Mat Y)
{
    /*sub2ind(size(a), rowsub, colsub)
    sub2ind(size(a), 2     , 3 ) = 6
    a = 1 2 3 ;
    4 5 6
    rowsub + colsub-1 * numberof rows in matrix*/

    std::vector<int> index;
    cv::transpose(Y,Y);
    cv::MatConstIterator_<int> iterX = X.begin<int>(), it_endX = X.end<int>();
    cv::MatConstIterator_<int> iterY = Y.begin<int>(), it_endY = Y.end<int>();
    for (int j = 0; j < X.cols; ++j,++iterX)    
    {
        //running on each col of y matrix
        for (int i =0 ;i < Y.cols; ++i,++iterY )
        {   
            int rowsub = *iterY;
            int colsub = *iterX;
            int res = rowsub + ((colsub-1)*height);
            index.push_back(res);
        }
        int x = 5;
    }   
    cv::Mat M(index) ;
    return M;   
}
```